# Updating a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update a document in a mongodb database and a failing miserable.

I am using node.js and this driver: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Here is my code:

```
db.collection('test').update({ _id: '5210f6bc75c7c33408000001' }, {$set: { title: "new title"}, {w:1}, function(err) {
      if (err) console.warn(err.message);
      else console.log('successfully updated');
    });
```

Here is my database:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "type" : "new", "title" : "my title", "desc" : [  "desc 1" ], "_id" : ObjectId("
5210f6bc75c7c33408000001") }
>
```

I create a `successfully updated` message, but the change hasn't happened.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your id attribute to be an ObjectId

```
db.collection('test').update({ _id: ObjectId('5210f6bc75c7c33408000001') }, {$set: { title: "new title"}, {w:1}, function(err) {
      if (err) console.warn(err.message);
      else console.log('successfully updated');
    });
```

The _id field is actually an object of type ObjectId, not a string.  The reason it succeeds is because there is no error, it just doesn't find any objects that have an _id with that String.